# Java - "intercept" a private method

Tags: java, reflection

I know this has been asked before, and the answer is usually "you can't" and/or "don't," but I'm trying this anyway.

The context is that I'm trying to set up some "black magic" to aid in testing.  My code is running ultimately under JUnit and the nature of the system is such that, while I have access to most any library I could want (ByteBuddy, Javassist, etc), I can't play around with the code prior to it running, I'm stuck with working with classes on the fly.

Here's the setup:

```
// External Library that I have no control over:
package com.external.stuff;

/** This is the thing I ultimately want to capture a specific instance of. */
public class Target {...}

public interface IFace {
  void someMethod();
}

class IFaceImpl {
  @Override  
  void someMethod() {
     ...
     Target t = getTarget(...);
     doSomethingWithTarget(t);
     ...
  }

  private Target getTarget() {...}
  private void doSomethingWithTarget(Target t) {...}
}
```

Within my test magic-ness, I have an instance of IFace, which I happen to know is an IFaceImpl.  What I'd *like* to do is be able to steal the instance of `Target` produced internally.  Effectively, this would have the same effect as the following (if private methods were overrideable):

```
class MyIFaceImpl extends IFaceImpl{
  private Consumer<Target> targetStealer;

  @Override  
  void someMethod() {
     ...
     Target t = getTarget(...);
     doSomethingWithTarget(t);
     ...
  }

  /** "Override" either this method or the next one. */
  private Target getTarget() {
    Target t = super.getTarget();
    targetStealer.accept(t);
    return t;
  }

  private void doSomethingWithTarget(Target t) {
    targetStealer.accept(t);
    super.doSomethingWithTarget(t);
  }
}
```

But, of course, that doesn't work as private methods cannot be overridden.
So the next type of approach would be something like `ByteBuddy` or `Javassist`

```
public static class Interceptor {
  private final Consumer<Target> targetStealer;
  // ctor elided

  public  void doSomethingWithTarget(Target t) {
    targetStealer.accept(t);
  }
}


/** Using ByteBuddy. */
IFace byteBuddyBlackMagic(
    IFace iface /* known IFaceImpl*/,
    Consumer<Target> targetStealer) {
  return (IFace) new ByteBuddy()
      .subClass(iface.getClass())
      .method(ElementMatchers.named("doSomethingWithTarget"))
      .intercept(MethodDelegation.to(new Interceptor(t))
      .make()
      .load(...)
      .getLoaded()
      .newInstance()
}

/** Or, using Javassist */
IFace javassistBlackMagic(
    IFace iface /* known IFaceImpl*/,
    Consumer<Target> targetStealer) {
  ProxyFactory factory = new ProxyFactory();
  factory.setSuperClass(iface.getClass());
  Class subClass = factory.createClass();
  IFace = (IFace) subClass.newInstance();

  MethodHandler handler =
      new MethodHandler() {
        @Override
        public Object invoke(Object self, Method thisMethod, Method proceed, Object[] args) throws Throwable {
          if (thisMethod.getName().equals("doSomethingWithTarget")) {
            consumer.accept((Target) args[0]);
          }
          return proceed.invoke(self, args);
        }
      };
  ((ProxyObject) instance).setHandler(handler);
  return instance;
}
```

and as I was testing out these pattern, it worked in other cases where the method I wanted to intercept was package-local, but not for private methods (expected for ByteBuddy, per [the documentation](http://bytebuddy.net/javadoc/1.6.3/net/bytebuddy/implementation/MethodDelegation.html#to-java.lang.Object-)).

So, yes, I recognize that this is attempting to invoke dark powers, and that this is normally frowned upon.  The question remains, is this doable?

Comment: Just don't test private methods. Test the public methods; their internal organization should be unimportant.

Comment: Conversely, if you really need to test (or mock) a private method, consider making it package private instead.  That's usually a good enough flag to let others know they shouldn't mess around with it, while still allowing most test mock libraries to easily access it.

Comment: Copy the source code of `IFaceImpl`, change its' visibility, compile it, carefully adjust the classpath so your version of `IFaceImpl` is loaded before the external library. jvm internally uses `URLClassPath` to find class files, which scans each location in the classpath one by one, from left to right. This should work at least on openjdk

Comment: So, regarding responses thus far...

1. I'm not trying to test these methods, I just want access to the internal instance of Target that they use.
2. I don't have access to change the visibility of the method.
3. This wasn't covered in the original, but I also don't have the means to ensure what version would be picked up.  Obviously, I could just copy the class and edit it and use the copy, but there are also reasons not to do that here that are at least as strong as not using black magic.

Comment: @BenLeitner can you do this setup on application startup? As there is neat trick you can do, but only if you can execute some code BEFORE that IFaceImpl is loaded.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

using javassist you can instrument the someMethod( ) in the IClassImpl class to send the instance of the TargetClass to someother class and store it there or do other manipulations using the instance created.

this can be achieved using the insertAfter( ) method in javassist .

For example :

```
method.insertAfter( "TestClass.storeTargetInst(t)" ); // t is the instance of Target class in IClassImpl.someMethod
```

`TestClass{
public static void storeTargetInst(Object o){ ### code to store instance ###}
}`

The insertAfter() method injects a line of code before the return statement of a method or as the last line of a method in case of void methods.

Refer [this link](http://www.javassist.org/tutorial/tutorial.html) for more information on the methods available for instrumentation.
Hope this helps!

Comment: This looks like it would be exactly what I was looking for, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you can execute some code in like public static void main block, or just before `IFaceImpl` is loaded, then you can use javassist to edit that class directly before it is loaded - so you can change method to be public, add another one, etc:

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        // this would return "original"
//        System.out.println(IFace.getIFace().getName());
        // IFaceImpl class is not yet loaded by jvm
        CtClass ctClass = ClassPool.getDefault().get("lib.IFaceImpl");
        CtMethod getTargetMethod = ctClass.getDeclaredMethod("getTarget");
        getTargetMethod.setBody("{ return app.Main.myTarget(); }");
        ctClass.toClass(); // now we load our modified class

        // yay!
        System.out.println(IFace.getIFace().getName());
    }

    public static Target myTarget() {
        return new Target("modified");
    }
}
```

where library code is like this:

```
public interface IFace {
    String getName();
    static IFace getIFace() {
        return new IFaceImpl();
    }
}
class IFaceImpl implements IFace {
    @Override public String getName() {
        return getTarget().getName();
    }
    private Target getTarget() {
        return new Target("original");
    }
}
public class Target {
    private final String name;
    public Target(String name) {this.name = name;}
    public String getName() { return this.name; }
}
```

If there is no way to execute your code before that class is loaded, then you need to use instrumentalization, I will use `byte-buddy-agent` library to make this simpler:

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        // prints "original"
        System.out.println(IFace.getIFace().getName());

        Instrumentation instrumentation = ByteBuddyAgent.install();
        Class<?> implClass = IFace.getIFace().getClass();
        CtClass ctClass = ClassPool.getDefault().get(implClass.getName());
        CtMethod getTargetMethod = ctClass.getDeclaredMethod("getTarget");
        getTargetMethod.setBody("{ return app.Main.myTarget(); }");
        instrumentation.redefineClasses(new ClassDefinition(implClass, ctClass.toBytecode()));

        // yay!
        System.out.println(IFace.getIFace().getName());
    }

    public static Target myTarget() {
        return new Target("modified");
    }
}
```

Both versions might be much more problematic to run on java 9 and above due to how modules work, you might need to add additional startup flags.
Note that on java 8 instrumentalization might not be present on client JRE. (but with few more hacks can be added, even at runtime)

Comment: On startup, no, but I can run code prior to the instance in question being created.

Comment: @BenLeitner just try both solutions then, but first one should be placed in a spot where your code is executed first, to give it most chances of working.